# Expresión regular que encuentre un guión bajos seguido de números

Tags: javascript, regex

Como sería la expresión regular en la que encuentre al final de una url, un guión bajo y luego números en Javascript? Por ejemplo:

Encontrar **_12345**

```
http://www.miweb.com/path1/path2/articulo_12345
```

Mejor sería si además puedo especificarle parte de la url. Usando el ejemplo anterior:

1. Encontrar el dominio `http://www.miweb.com/`.
2. Contenga dos carpetas/path que tengan cualquier nombre.
3. Encuentre guión bajo y los numeros.

Ejemplos:

`http://www.miweb.com/primero/segundo/articulo_12345` > **Match**
`http://www.otraweb.com/primero/segundo/articulo_559` > **No match**
`http://www.miweb.com/cualquier/path/casa_54684` > **Match**
`http://www.miweb.com/path/casa_9124` > **No match**

Comment: indiva el lenguaje que estas usando

Comment: Disculpa, en Javascript

Comment: Mariano te invocamos XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sería algo así:

```
http://www\.miweb\.com/\w+/\w+/\w+_\d{5}
```

Comment: Excelente, muchas gracias!

Comment: Jonnathan: si en un caso existe una url que tenga varias palabras separadas por guión medio ¿Como sería? Por ej `http://www.miweb.com/primero/segundo/articulo-con-mas-de-una-palabra_12345`